# Are these categories toposes?

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

Apart from usual examples of toposes, I'd like to know if some of the following categories and some of their subcategories are known to be toposes :

- the category $\text{Heyt}$ of Heyting algebras and morphisms between them (and subcategories like the category $\text{CHeyt}$ of complete Heyting algebras),
- the category $\text{Loc}$ of locales and morphisms between them,
- the category $\text{Frm}$ of frames and morphisms between them ($\text{Loc}=\text{Frm}^{\text{op}}$),
- the category $\text{Bool}$ of boolean algebras).

Edit : and what about the category $\text{Stone}$ of Stone spaces ?

Comment: None of the above: all of these categories are not even cartesian closed.